# Creating a notification system using socket.io and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

Im developing a site similar to Youtube. Logged in users can subscribe to channels and receive updates whenever a video is uploaded via notifications (like how Facebook notification is).

I would need to send notifications to users who are subscribed to certain channels so this means sending notifications per socket. The problem is how would I approach this?

1. Create a socket.io room for each channel then make the user 'join' that room so I could message that room to push notifications to the subscribers. problem is there would be 100,000 rooms if there are 100,000 channels.
2. Create a redis connection. A PHP script will save a key=>value pair eg(channelid => subscriberid) and then let nodeJS fetch this, then notify the users. Problem with this is its like sending tens and thousands of key->value pairs to a redis server.

Site is purely PHP/MySQL. Will just use socket.io and nodejs for the notification server/client.

Comment: The first question here is whether you're operating on a scale that can be served by one notification server of if you will need to design a multi-server solution because the design is likely very different (and not as simple) for multi-server.  This will involve understanding what scale you really have to design for and then testing whether a single server can handle that scale.

Comment: Actually I was hoping that there is a way to make this a small scale server. Something that can co-exist with the HTTP server for the site. Right now my 3rd option is to send a key value pair through redis, but the value is an object containing all the subscribers 'userid' which I can loop through in nodejs then notify each. Again, not really that great because it may contain thousands of subscribers therefore thousands of loop.